# How to populate MsSQL database using data from a rest api inside a aspnet mvc controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

So Im trying to make a CRUD application using aspnet mvc and I want to populate my own db using the data from an API. Here's the code for the Index method inside my controller and the model used for the controller

```
    `public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
      {
          List<Employee> EmpInfo = new List<Employee>();
          string Baseurl = "https://northwind.vercel.app/api/employess";
            string connectionUrl = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-     WebApplication3-020c3741-9f8f-428c-848a-    6bfe5a7d80c9;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
        
          using (var client = new HttpClient())
           {

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

              client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
              //Define request data format  
              client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new   MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //get data from nw api 
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("northwind.now.sh/api/employess");

            // check for con success 
            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(EmpResponse);


            }
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionUrl))
            {
                connection.Open();
                foreach (int i = 0;i < EmpInfo.Count;i++) {

                    string sqlCommandText = "INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(@id, @lastName, @firstName,@title,@titleOfCourtesy,@birthDate,@hireDate,@reportsTo)";


                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandText, connection)
                    {
                    
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", EmpInfo.ElementAt(i).id; // Replace with your actual values
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", EmpInfo.ElementAt(i).lastName);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", EmpInfo.ElementAt(i).firstName);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", EmpInfo.ElementAt(i).title); // Replace with your actual values
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titleOfCourtesy", EmpInfo.ElementAt(i).titleOfCourtesy);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthDate", EmpInfo.ElementAt(i).birthDate);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hireDate", EmpInfo.ElementAt(i).hireDate); // Replace with your actual values
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportsTo", EmpInfo.ElementAt(i).reportsTo);
         

                    // Execute the command
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                } 

            }
            //returning the employee list to view  

            return View(EmpInfo);
        }
    }`
```

Code for my Employee model

```
 `namespace WebApplication3.Models
     {
      public class Employee
      {
          public int id { get; set; }
          public string lastName { get; set; }
          public string firstName { get; set; }
          public string title { get; set; }
          public string titleOfCourtesy { get; set; }
          public string birthDate { get; set; }
          public string hireDate { get; set; }
          public Address Address { get; set; }
          public string reportsTo { get; set; }

          public Employee()
         {

         }
     }
 }`
```

I tried to get data from an API and populate my own database with it. But my database is empty everytime i try to run a query.

Comment: Just saying that the DB is empty doesn't help us to help you.  You need to debug the code and find out exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Potential issues: 1. Have you checked that `EmpInfo` is not an empty list (actually receives data over the wire). 2. Have you checked that the database user has write access to the database?

Comment: Are you using `AttachDbFilename` in the connection string? If so, bad idea, as it creates a copy of your database which disappears when you close the connection. Side note: do not use `.Result`, instead use `await` to await the result of an async operation. Also specify the columns you are inserting into `INSERT Table (column1, Column2...) VALUES (...)` and specify the parameter types and lengths explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions are:

1. Check the API url. Most of the times you should input full url, I mean include other parts like "https://" etc.
2. Since you're using an async method, wrap your code inside a `try...catch` block. This lets you catch the exception (if there's one) that is causing your problem.
3. Place some break points to check if data are correctly obtained/passed

Also, I see that `BaseUrl` and the url you provide on `GetAsync` are different, I'm assuming this is correct.

I  also see that you only check if the status code is success (so, a 200), what if there's another status, like a 400 or 500?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the database using the query tool and all I needed to do was

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table ON

INSERT INTO Table

            (val1
             val2,
             val3)
VALUES      (value,
             anothervalue,
             anothervalue1)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 OFF
```